# MariaDB Galera Clustering - Active Active - Operation not permitted error

Tags: mysql, cluster, mysql-cluster, mariadb

I am having issues with MariaDB and Galera running on RHEL 6.4 & 6.2 64bit servers and getting them to cluster. I installed the required RPM's for Galera clustering:

- MariaDB-Galera-server
- MariaDB-client
- MariaDB-compat
- MariaDB-common
- MariaDB-shared
- MariaDB-test
- galera

Then after installing MariaDB and all of its components, I checked the directories where it normally keeps its files, `/var/lib/mysql/` and `/var/log/mysql/` and performed a

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql/
```

I started both servers in standalone mode and configured a replication user:

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'mariadb-user'@'localhost' identified by 'password' with grant option;
grant all privileges on *.* to 'mariadb-user'@'%' identified by 'password' with grant option;
```

That way, I would have a user for the databases to communicate with. Then I edited my configs on both the Master and Slave nodes:

```
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
#
# See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql/
#

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]
general_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log
general_log=1
log_warning=2
log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log
#log-bin=/var/log/mysql-bin.log
log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql-slow-queries.log
# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-5.5 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mysqld-5.5]

# These two groups are only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://mariadb-master.net,mariadb-slave.net
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
binlog_format=ROW
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
wsrep_cluster_name=corp-zabbix-server
wsrep_debug=on
wsrep_sst_auth=mariadb-user:cerner
##wsrep_sst_auth=root:
wsrep_sst_method=mysqldump
##wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup
[mariadb-5.5]
```

Once the configs were in place, I made sure that the firewalls allowed the traffic to go through, basically by just wiping them out `iptables -F`. Then I initialized the cluster on the master using:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start --wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://
```

The Process comes up on the Master node, and on the Slave node using:

```
service mysql start
```

The slave node then connects for a bit, exchanges states, and exits saying that the operation is not permitted.

[MariaDB_Error_Log at Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/8tSAtfT2)

This is the output from `/var/log/mysql/mysql.log`:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.32-MariaDB-log (MariaDB Server, wsrep_23.7.5.rXXXX). started with:
Tcp port: 0  Unix socket: (null)
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.32-MariaDB-log (MariaDB Server, wsrep_23.7.5.rXXXX). started with:
Tcp port: 0  Unix socket: (null)
Time                 Id Command    Argument
130910  8:18:48     3 Connect   mariadb-user@mariadb-master.net as anonymous on
                    3 Query     select @@version_comment limit 1
                    3 Query     SET wsrep_on=OFF
                    3 Query     SELECT @@GENERAL_LOG
                    3 Quit
                    4 Connect   mariadb-user@mariadb-master.net as anonymous on
                    4 Query     select @@version_comment limit 1
                    4 Query     SET wsrep_on=OFF
                    4 Query     SELECT @@SLOW_QUERY_LOG
                    4 Quit
                    5 Connect   mariadb-user@mariadb-master.net as anonymous on
                    5 Query     select @@version_comment limit 1
                    5 Query     SET wsrep_on=OFF
                    5 Query     SET GLOBAL GENERAL_LOG=OFF
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.32-MariaDB-log (MariaDB Server, wsrep_23.7.5.rXXXX). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
130910  8:18:50     7 Query     SET GLOBAL SLOW_QUERY_LOG=1
                    7 Quit
130910  8:18:51     8 Connect   mariadb-user@mariadb-master.net as anonymous on
                    8 Query     select @@version_comment limit 1
                    8 Query     SET wsrep_on=OFF
                    8 Query     SELECT @@GENERAL_LOG
                    8 Quit
                    9 Connect   mariadb-user@mariadb-master.net as anonymous on
                    9 Query     select @@version_comment limit 1
                    9 Query     SET wsrep_on=OFF
                    9 Query     SELECT @@SLOW_QUERY_LOG
                    9 Quit
                   10 Connect   mariadb-user@mariadb-master.net as anonymous on
                   10 Query     select @@version_comment limit 1
                   10 Query     SET wsrep_on=OFF
                   10 Query     SET GLOBAL GENERAL_LOG=OFF
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.32-MariaDB-log (MariaDB Server, wsrep_23.7.5.rXXXX). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
130910  8:18:52    12 Query     SET GLOBAL SLOW_QUERY_LOG=1
                   12 Quit
130910  8:18:53    13 Connect   mariadb-user@mariadb-master.net as anonymous on
                   13 Query     select @@version_comment limit 1
                   13 Query     SET wsrep_on=OFF
                   13 Query     SELECT @@GENERAL_LOG
                   13 Quit
                   14 Connect   mariadb-user@mariadb-master.net as anonymous on
                   14 Query     select @@version_comment limit 1
                   14 Query     SET wsrep_on=OFF
                   14 Query     SELECT @@SLOW_QUERY_LOG
                   14 Quit
                   15 Connect   mariadb-user@mariadb-master.net as anonymous on
                   15 Query     select @@version_comment limit 1
                   15 Query     SET wsrep_on=OFF
                   15 Query     SET GLOBAL GENERAL_LOG=OFF
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.32-MariaDB-log (MariaDB Server, wsrep_23.7.5.rXXXX). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
130910  8:18:55    17 Query     SET GLOBAL SLOW_QUERY_LOG=1
                   17 Quit
```

I'm not sure what else I should do. I had this cluster working before, but I reverted to the snapshot right after I had the OS baseline completed. So, in my mind, it should have worked the same way, but it didn't. Should I create a local user on the boxes themselves named the same as the database user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the error messages on the pastebin link, on line 18 and 19, there is a reference to this:

```
130906 12:47:32 [ERROR] mysqld: File '/var/log/mysql-slow-queries.log' not found (Errcode: 13)
130906 12:47:32 [ERROR] Could not use /var/log/mysql-slow-queries.log for logging (error 13). Turning logging off for the whole duration of the MySQL server process. To turn it on again: fix the cause, shutdown the MySQL server and restart it.
```

What I had done is when I made my config file, I finger fudged a line:

```
log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql-slow-queries.log
```

Once I edited this line to reflect:

```
log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow-queries.log
```

The cluster magically worked. I am able to replicate between databases and have them function now. I'm not exactly sure why that one line would prevent everything from working, but it did.